# Hatcher Theorem 2.16

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have a question regarding theorem 2.16 in Hatcher's Algebraic topology book.

Theorem :$ \cdots  \to H_n(A) \stackrel{ i_{\star}}{\to} H_n(B) \stackrel{ j_{\star}}{\to} H_n(C) \stackrel{ \partial }{\to} H_{n-1}(A) \to \cdots $ is exact . Where $ A , B , C $ are chain complexes with : $   0 \to A_{n} \stackrel{i}{\to} B_n \stackrel{j}{\to} C_n \to 0 $ being a short exact sequence for all $ n $ .

I cannot quite understand why $ Im(j_{\star}) \subseteq ker(\partial) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[b] \in H_n(B)$. That is, $\partial_B b = 0$ and we have quotiented by 
$[b] = [b']$ whenever $b = b' + \partial_B b''$.

Let us also recall the definition of $\partial : H_n(C) \to H_{n-1}(A)$, the connecting homomorphism. Not to be confused with $\partial_B : B_n \to B_{n-1}$.

$\partial [c]$ is defined to be the class $[a]$ such that $[ia] = [\partial_B b]$ with $[jb] = [c]$.

I am legally required to include the following picture (even though I know you have Hatcher):

[image: the definition of the connecting hom]

Now $\partial j_* [b] = \partial [jb]$ should be the $[a]$ such that 
$[ia] = [\partial_B b]$. But recall $\partial_B b = 0$, since $[b] \in \text{Ker}(\partial_B) / \text{Im}(\partial_B)$ can only happen if $b \in \text{Ker}(\partial_B)$!

Thus we want $[a]$ such that $[ia] = [0]$, but by the assumed short exactness, $ia = 0$ exactly when $a=0$. Thus $\partial j_* [b] = [0]$, as desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^